# Bootstrap Datetime picker not accepting options

Tags: javascript, html

On a page that I am working on there is a datetime picker. It is seemingly working fine, however none of the options seem to be registering and for the life of me I cannot figure out why.

I have commented out all javascript, html and external libraries that may be interfering with it. I have made sure all the files are correct. I have made sure it's being called...anything and everything I can think of.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="form-group row " >
    <label class="col-md-2 form-control-label" for="StartDate">Start Date</label>
    <div class="controls " >    
        <div class="input-group date col-md-3 datePicker">
             <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="StartDate" name="datePicker">
             <span class="input-group-addon add-on"> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> </span> 
        </div>                          
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.datePicker').datetimepicker({
         format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',//This is not working
         minDate:d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1) //neither is this
     })
     .find("input")
     .end();
```

Comment: Try lowercase dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Have you tried to use `id` instead of `class`?

Comment: @karen, upper or lower case made no difference.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú, Yes, I have tried using the id instead of the class

Comment: Could you make this project available on CodeSandbox, for example. It would be much easier to deal with.

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in a 'document ready' check? All the examples look like they're wrapped in one `$(function() { ... })`

Comment: @BrettEast, Yes the code is wrapped in a document ready.

Comment: Is bootstrap datepicker a separate package or external library? Or is it bundled into the bootstrap javascript? And how much of it is working, just the appearance or is the calendar with the numbers showing up?

Comment: @BrettEast, it is an external bootstrap library. The only thing, as mentioned in the title, not working is the options.

Comment: The date format works "fine" tho .. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld2rtsb5/3/) (can't test the other as I don't have the value `d`), this might be an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem

Answer (score 0):

This example definitely except format you can test by uncommenting format lines one by one. I hope this is usable to your request.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<body>
   <div class="container">
  <div  class="input-append date">
    <input id="datetimepicker1" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" type="text"></input>
  </div>
   </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
     //format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss'
     format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
     //format: 'hh:mm:ss'
    });
  });
</script>
```